# calculating the expected time in an exhaustive search

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Assume we are trying to crack a password. There are $2^{88}$ possibilities.

I have a machine that can test $2^{40}$ passwords per second.

What is the expected time to find the password if I use exhaustive search.

my answer was $ 2^{88}/2^{40}=2^{48}$ seconds

however, the correct answer is $2^{47}$ seconds, could someone explain to me why is that?

Comment: Books are not always right.

Comment: Hint: $2^{48}$ is the worst-case time.

Comment: @Priyatham: as a rule of thumbs, books are right and skeptical readers are wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The lack of proper context tripped me, hehe. You are right, though.

Answer (score 1):

The *worst-case* time until you find the password is $2^{48}$ seconds, but the *expected* (that is, average) time until you come across it is half as long as that. Presumably your search will terminate when you find the right password, which, on average, will happen somewhere in the middle of the $2^{88}$ passwords there are to try.

Of course $2^{47}$ seconds and $2^{48}$ seconds are both, for this purpose, "inhumanly long". (But the hidden assumption that all $2^{88}$ possible passwords are equally likely to be *the one* probably deserves some reconsideration. With a smart search strategy, most passwords that *people actually choose* and remember can be cracked plenty faster than that).